# Фрагменты и кнопка назад

Tags: android, android-fragment

Использую архитектуру с фрагментами. (1 `Activity`, и общий контейнер для фрагментов).

Появилась следующая проблема:
Если открыть фрагмент `ProfileEditFragment` и нажать на кнопку назад, то в методе `onBackPressed` у `MainActivity` успешно вызовется `super.onBackPressed();` и произойдёт следующий трюк:

Сначала откроется предыдущий фрагмент (`MapFragment`), затем сразу же откроется фрагмент `ProfileEditFragment`, из которого, по сути, и была нажата кнопка назад. В чём причина такого поведения - разобраться пока что не удалось.
Пробовал так же использовать `getSupportFragmentManager().popBaskStack();`, но в таком случае, реакции не будет никакой.

Причём, перед вызовом проверяю состояние бэк-стэка, фрагменты в нём есть.

**MainActivity:**

```
  @Override
    public void showMapFragment() {
//        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,getSupportFragmentManager().POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        //mainPresenter.clearActiveLoginFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.ltContainer, MapFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void showProfileEditFragment() {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.ltContainer, ProfileEditFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMainBackStack() {

        int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        Log.d("COunt in backstack", count + "");
//        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
//        Log.d("COunt in backstack",getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()
//        +"");
//        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
//        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

**ProfileEditFragment**

```
private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_profile_edit;


    //@formatter:off
    @InjectPresenter ProfileEditPresenter mProfileEditPresenter;
    //@formatter:on
    public static ProfileEditFragment newInstance() {
        ProfileEditFragment fragment = new ProfileEditFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }
```

**MapFragment**

```
//@formatter:off
    @InjectPresenter MapPresenter mapPresenter;
    @BindView(R.id.map) ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView mapView;
    @BindView(R.id.fbMenu) FloatingActionButton fbMenu;
    //@formatter:on

    private MapController mapController; //// FIXME: 11.11.2016

    public static MapFragment newInstance() {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        setupMap();
        showMapButtons();
        mapPresenter.checkPermission();
        setupListeners();
        return view;
    }

    private void setupListeners() {
        fbMenu.setOnClickListener(v->mapPresenter.onClickMenu());
    }

    private void setupMap() {
        mapController = mapView.getMapController();
        mapController.getMapRotator().a(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void showMapButtons() {
        mapView.showZoomButtons(true);
        mapView.showScaleView(false);
        mapView.showJamsButton(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void showProfileEditFragment() {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showProfileEditFragment();
    }
```

---

**UPD:** [англоязычный стек](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549060/fragments-and-onbackpressed)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в неправильном использовании библиотеки Moxy c фрагментами. Не сразу заметил причину.

https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/issues/50